Naming symmetries of trapezoids (on the plane)

I am trying to work out suitable classification of the two classes of trilateral trapezoid being represented by the different colours.
For the left hexagon, the trapezoids are coloured such that they mirror along any drawn line of symmetry.
For the right hexagon, the trapezoids are coloured according to the orientation of their longest line.
Maybe that's good enough - but it doesn't sound proper?!
Grünbaum & Shephard (1986) are useful but I don't fully understand their nomenclature.  I believe that, if we just consider the hexagons coloured by their trapezoids, the right-hand pattern could be p6m[3]2 with the isohedral type IH77, (from the p6m wallpaper group).
I also know that the both patterns follow the p31m wallpaper group (albeit the unit tile is 300% the length of the one on the left when preserving colour), however, the wallpaper group identity is not really very descriptive.

The answer to this was in the book all along: Grünbaum & Shephard (1986) -where chapter 8 deals with all sorts of colourings of tiles.
Just on the off-chance that someone has a similar problem, I have represented the diagrams from the relevant page..

... and then an overlay shows that the tilings match
[
$p31m[3]{_2}$ (left tiling)
$p31m[3]{_1}$ (right tiling)
There are 23 periodic 3-colour groups, and these two are the only ones which are available for $p31m$. (p419) (hence the subscript)
You might note that the representative tilings match the hexagons that the trapezoids are made from - each of the underlying chevrons is covered by two trapezoids along the direction of the chevron centre (this is relevant to colourings).  Nevertheless I believe that this is correct, because the orientation of the trapezoid needs preserving and a hexagonal tiling would not do that.
The authors point out that there are exactly 59 3-color pattern types (Lemma 8.3.2). (This is the $PP25[3]{_i}$ numbering but I'm confused because on p416 they are named $PP23[3]{_i}$ - but I might be missing something obvious!)
